# "Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading" using Client.map()

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to use `dask.distributed` to concurrently update a Postgresql database based on content from several CSV files.  Ideally, we'd distribute CSV files among N workers where each worker would insert CSV file content into the database.  However, we get a `Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading` exception when using `Client.map()` when distributing tasks to workers.

This is a condensed version of the code:

```py
def _work(csv_path):
   db = Database() # encapsulates interaction w/ postgresql database
   db.open()

   count = 0

   with csv_path.open('r') as csv_file:
       reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

       for record in reader:
           db.insert(record)
           count += 1

   db.close()

   return count


client = Client(processes=False)

csv_files = Path('/data/files/').glob('*.csv')

csv_futures = client.map(_work, csv_files) # error occurs here

for finished in  as_completed(csv_futures):
   count = finished.result()
   print(count)
```

Based on related stackoverflow and github issues, I successfully used `cloudpickle` to serialize and de-serialize the function and arguments.

```
cloudpickle.loads(cloudpickle.dumps(_work))
Out[69]: <function _work(csv_path)>
```

and

```
files = list(Path('/data/files/').glob('*.csv'))
files
Out[73]: 
[PosixPath('/data/files/208.csv'),
 PosixPath('/data/files/332.csv'),
 PosixPath('/data/files/125.csv'),
 PosixPath('/data/files/8.csv')]
cloudpickle.loads(cloudpickle.dumps(files))
Out[74]: 
[PosixPath('/data/files/208.csv'),
 PosixPath('/data/files/332.csv'),
 PosixPath('/data/files/125.csv'),
 PosixPath('/data/files/8.csv')]
```

So, the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The exact exception was this:

```
  File "/Users/may/anaconda/envs/eagle-i/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 841, in save_file
    raise pickle.PicklingError("Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading: %s" % obj.mode)
_pickle.PicklingError: Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading: a
```

Stepping through the debugger, I was curious as to what `obj` was, which was this:

`<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/logs/ei_sched.log' mode='a' encoding='UTF-8'>`

In the example code snippet given above, I left out calls to our logger, and it was of this that `cloudpickle` was complaining.  The logging was a leftover artifact of this functionality *before* trying to use dask to parallelize this functionality.  Once I removed the logging calls from the function passed to `Client.map()`, things worked as expected.

As an aside, this was a good catch from `cloudpickle` because logging to a single file should not be done from dask workers.